# How can I have output from one named pipe fed back into another named pipe?

Tags: bash, pipe, named-pipes, sh, mkfifo

I'm adding some custom logging functionality to a bash script, and can't figure out why it won't take the output from one named pipe and feed it back into another named pipe.

Here is a basic version of the script (http://pastebin.com/RMt1FYPc):

```
#!/bin/bash

PROGNAME=$(basename $(readlink -f $0))
LOG="$PROGNAME.log"
PIPE_LOG="$PROGNAME-$$-log"
PIPE_ECHO="$PROGNAME-$$-echo"

# program output to log file and optionally echo to screen (if $1 is "-e")
log () {
  if [ "$1" = '-e' ]; then 
    shift
    $@ > $PIPE_ECHO 2>&1 
  else 
    $@ > $PIPE_LOG 2>&1 
  fi
}

# create named pipes if not exist
if [[ ! -p $PIPE_LOG ]]; then 
  mkfifo -m 600 $PIPE_LOG
fi
if [[ ! -p $PIPE_ECHO ]]; then 
  mkfifo -m 600 $PIPE_ECHO
fi

# cat pipe data to log file
while read data; do
  echo -e "$PROGNAME: $data" >> $LOG 
done < $PIPE_LOG &

# cat pipe data to log file & echo output to screen
while read data; do
  echo -e "$PROGNAME: $data"
  log echo $data   # this doesn't work
  echo -e $data > $PIPE_LOG 2>&1   # and neither does this
  echo -e "$PROGNAME: $data" >> $LOG   # so I have to do this
done < $PIPE_ECHO &

# clean up temp files & pipes
clean_up () {
  # remove named pipes
  rm -f $PIPE_LOG
  rm -f $PIPE_ECHO
}
#execute "clean_up" on exit
trap "clean_up" EXIT 

log echo "Log File Only"
log -e echo "Echo & Log File"
```

I thought the commands on line 34 & 35 would take the `$data` from `$PIPE_ECHO` and output it to the `$PIPE_LOG`.  But, it doesn't work.  Instead I have to send that output directly to the log file, without going through the `$PIPE_LOG`.

Why is this not working as I expect?

EDIT: I changed the shebang to "bash".  The problem is the same, though.

SOLUTION:  [A.H.'s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9352641/how-can-i-have-output-from-one-named-pipe-fed-back-into-another-named-pipe/9359882#9359882) helped me understand that I wasn't using named pipes correctly.  I have since solved my problem by not even using named pipes.  That solution is here:  http://pastebin.com/VFLjZpC3

Comment: You say it's a bash script, yet you're specifying `/bin/sh` on the first line of the script.  Are you SURE you need to do this in bash?  Remember that bash is not installed by default in every operating system.

Comment: I'd say the potential problem is, if you run this script using its path, instead of bash [path], you will invoke the "sh" version of bash (even if it's the same executable), which doesn't work exactly the same (limitations).

Comment: I tried replacing "sh" with "bash" and it works the same way (i.e. it doesn't).

Comment: There's something I don't understand: If I run it with "#!/bin/sh", I've got errors (21: [[: not found) and it doesn't work. If I run with "#!/bin/bash" it works as a charm (it echoes "Echo & Log File" and in the log file, I've got "Log File Only" AND "Echo & Log File"). Is it what you expect ?

Comment: I expect lines 34, 35, & 36 to all output "Echo & Log File" to the log file, thus there should be 3 "Echo & Log File" lines in the log file.  As it is, line 34 & 35 don't, but line 36 does.  I want to use the method in either 34 or 35, so I don't have to duplicate the output logic.  In the production version, I'm adding other things to the output such as a date time stamp, and it would be better for me to be able to pass the "pipe_echo" output to the "pipe_log" output rather than duplicate the logic of the "pipe_log" routine in the "pipe–echo" function.

Comment: Sorry I did'nt explain something : I just kept line 34 and removed 35 & 36. So I could see that line 34 worked (log echo $data). I've checked again with using again lines 35 and 36, and I've got 3 times the "Echo & Log File" in the log file. What Linux (or Unix) do you use? How do you invoke the script? I just run ./<script_name> on a debian Squeeze and it worked.

Comment: Weird, then.  It doesn't work for me.  When I just have line 34 in, I only get "Log File Only" in the log file, not "Echo & Log File".  I'm  running this on CentOS 6.2.  I invoke the script with `./<script_name>`.  In RHEL/CentOS, `/bin/sh` is symlinked to `/bin/bash`.  But, if you're using bash to run it, it should work the same as bash on CentOS I'd think.

Comment: Will try on RHEL 6.2 then. BTW, even if /bin/sh is linked to /bin/bash, it doesn't work the same because the exe looks at the invocation name. If it's "sh", then it behaves differently.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

it seems to me, you do not understand what a named pipe really is. A named pipe is not *one* stream like normal pipes. It is a *series* of normal pipes, because a named pipe can be closed and a close on the producer side is *might be* shown as a close on the consumer side.

The *might be* part is this: The consumer will read data until there is no more data. No more data means, that at the time of the `read` call no producer has the named pipe open. This means that multiple producer can feed one consumer only when there is no point in time without at least one producer. Think of it of door which closes automatically: If there is a steady stream of people keeping the door always open either by handing the doorknob to the next one or by squeezing multiple people through it at the same time, the door is open. But once the door is closed it stays closed.

A little demonstration should make the difference a little clearer:

Open three shells. **First** shell:

```
1> mkfifo xxx
1> cat xxx
```

no output is shown because `cat` has opened the named pipe and is waiting for data.

**Second** shell:

```
2> cat > xxx
```

no output, because this `cat` is a producer which keeps the named pipe open until we tell him to close it explicitly.

**Third** shell:

```
3> echo Hello > xxx
3>
```

This producer immediately returns.

**First shell**:

```
Hello
```

The consumer received data, wrote it and - since one more consumer keeps the door open, continues to wait.

**Third shell**

```
3> echo World > xxx
3>
```

**First shell**:

```
World
```

The consumer received data, wrote it and - since one more consumer keeps the door open, continues to wait.

**Second Shell**: write into the `cat > xxx` window:

```
And good bye!
(control-d key)
2>
```

**First shell**

```
And good bye!
1>
```

The <kbd>^D</kbd> key closed the last producer, the `cat > xxx`, and hence the consumer exits also.

---

In your case which means:

- Your `log` function will try to open and close the pipes multiple times. Not a good idea.
- Both your `while` loops exit earlier than you think. (check this with `(while ... done < $PIPE_X; echo FINISHED; ) &`
- Depending on the scheduling of your various producers and consumers the door might by slam shut sometimes and sometimes not - you have a race condition built in. (For testing you can add a `sleep 1` at the end of  the `log` function.)
- You "testcases" only tries each possibility once - *try* to use them multiple times (you will block, especially with the `sleep`s ), because your producer might not find any consumer.

So I can explain the problems in your code but I cannot tell you a solution because it is unclear what the edges of your requirements are.

Comment: Great answer, which states it very clear. But what is strange is that it behaves very differently in RHEL 6.2 and Debian Squeeze and I don't understand why. In RHEL, the first loop DOESN'T exit at all (stuck on a write instead.. not on the read). In Debian, sending multiple logs worked OK, but adding sleep caused the whole thing to hang. I'd like to go deeper into the subject.

Comment: @huelbois: As I wrote: It's a race-condition which is made explicit by the `sleep`: If there is no "steady stream" of producers "keeping the door open", the consumer will exit and the _next producer will block_. Without the sleep the "steady stream" is just more probable. Also different OS distros indicate different hardware and hence different scheduling behaviour.

Comment: @huelbois: I've tried to hide some internals but now I think it's better to name them for you: One critical difference between normal pipes and FIFOs (aka. named pipe) is _where_ blocking takes place normally: With standard pipes the cons. and prod. will block in `read`/`write` calls. FIFOs on the other hand usually block in the __open__ call for both the consumer and the producer! After both "have met" both `open` calls return and both the cons. and the prod. continue their work (possibly blocking again). This means that the synchronization is done during `open` and not during `read`/`write`.

Comment: Thanks, A.H. You're right... I didn't correctly understand how the FIFOs work.  Can you help me figure out how to make this work?  Here's what I'm trying to accomplish:  The above code is part of a startup script (rc.d/init.d) which executes another vendor-supplied script to start an application.  When the vendor-supplied script runs, it outputs messages to STDOUT (and finally exits).  I want to capture those messages, add a few things (timestamp, program name), and redirect the resulting messages to a log file (and optionally echo to STDOUT/terminal).

Comment: A.H.:  let me know if I should repost this as a new question.  I'm not sure of the etiquette on this.  Thank you!

Comment: @kipkoan: A new question would be better IMHO, because a) you should first look around if someone else already solved a problem like this (I would think so), b) it is a clean start - no mixing of different stuff and c) you can describe the real problem more concise.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the problem is in the "cat pipe data to log file" part.

Let's see: you use a "&" to put the loop in the background, I guess you mean it must run in parallel with the second loop.

But the problem is you don't even need the "&", because as soon as no more data is available in the fifo, the while..read stops. (still you've got to have some at first for the first read to work). The next read doesn't hang if no more data is available (which would pose another problem: how does your program stops ?).

I guess the while read checks if more data is available in the file before doing the read and stops if it's not the case.

You can check with this sample:

```
mkfifo foo
while read data; do echo $data; done < foo
```

This script will hang, until you write anything from another shell (or bg the first one). But it ends as soon as a read works.

Edit: 
I've tested on RHEL 6.2 and it works as you say (eg : bad!).

The problem is that, after running the script (let's say script "a"), you've got an "a" process remaining. So, yes, in some way the script hangs as I wrote before (not that stupid answer as I thought then :) ). Except if you write only one log (be it log file only or echo,in this case it works).

(It's the read loop from PIPE_ECHO that hangs when writing to PIPE_LOG and leaves a process running each time).

I've added a few debug messages, and here is what I see:

- only one line is read from PIPE_LOG and after that, the loop ends
- then a second message is sent to the PIPE_LOG (after been received from the PIPE_ECHO), but the process no longer reads from PIPE_LOG => the write hangs.

When you ls -l /proc/[pid]/fd, you can see that the fifo is still open (but deleted).
If fact, the script exits and removes the fifos, but there is still one process using it.
If you don't remove the log fifo at the cleanup and cat it, it will free the hanging process.

Hope it will help...

Comment: You can try running this script.  It doesn't hang.  The problem is that lines 34 & 35 don't output anything to the log file.

Comment: You're right, sorry. But learned something with while read and fifo today!